# VMWare Ubuntu guest multitouch touchpad

Tags: vmware-player

Related: [Use Synaptics Touchpad Scroll in VMware Guest](https://superuser.com/questions/131297/use-synaptics-touchpad-scroll-in-vmware-guest)

I've read that it's not possible to enable multitouch in vmware guest.

What confuses me, is that when I use something special (like two finger scroll) in guest OS, I can see the cursor change to the scrolling one.

Is this some kind of virtualization bug or is there a possibility that I can enable multitouch in guest?

Host: Windows 7

Guest: Ubuntu 12.04

[image]

EDIT:

I noticed strange behavior: When I have a finger on touchpad and slide another two fingers, it "works" (it's very laggy and strange).

Comment: 2016 update: on Windows hosts, just download and run this after spinning up the VM: https://bitbucket.org/DouglasCameron/windows-trackpad-scroller-for-vmware/downloads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for Windows hosts!

It's called [two-finger-scroll](http://code.google.com/p/two-finger-scroll/). Quote from the google page:

> This project aims at providing a tool for Windows platform adding some useful two finger gestures to Synaptics TouchPads. These TouchPads can be found in many todays laptops and many of them support multiple finger gestures.

With this enabled, the two finger scrolling is working properly in vmware.

Comment: 2016 update: on Windows hosts, just download and run this after spinning up the VM: https://bitbucket.org/DouglasCameron/windows-trackpad-scroller-for-vmware/downloads

Comment: @JorgeOrpinel Thank you very much for the 2016 update. It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using answer on the linked question at https://superuser.com/a/683726/261370

It is better in some ways. Circular scrolling works, for example, IIRC.